# openMapsWithItems cannot Invoke with argument list issue in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, apple-maps, swift2

I'm having a few issues converting my Swift 1.2 code to 2.0 - this is one of those issues.

I have a function which opens the iOS Maps app to give directions to a location. It was working fine until the conversion. Now I get the following error message:

```
Cannot invoke 'openMapsWithItems' with an argument list of type '([MKMapItem], launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject])'
```

This is my code (The error appears on the last line):

```
func openMapsWithDirections(longitude:Double, latitude:Double, placeName:String){

    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(longitude), CLLocationDegrees(latitude))
    var placemark:MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary:nil)
    var mapItem:MKMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = placeName
    let launchOptions:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, forKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey)
    var currentLocationMapItem:MKMapItem = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()

    MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([currentLocationMapItem, mapItem], launchOptions: launchOptions as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Declare `launchOptions` like `let launchOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject] = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey : MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]` and remove the `as [NSObject : AnyObject]`

Comment: Thanks Kametrixom, but I'm still getting the following error: 'Cannot invoke openMapsWithItems with an argument list of type ([MKMapItem], launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject])'. I've cleaned the build in case there was an issue there, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in [the pre-release developer resources for MKMapItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MKMapItem/openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:), `openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:` now has changed from taking a `[NSObject : AnyObject]!` to taking a `[String : AnyObject]?`, so you will have to declare (or cast) it as such.

Change in your code the line

```
let launchOptions:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving, forKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey)
```

to

```
let launchOptions = [MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving]
```

and the last line

```
MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([currentLocationMapItem, mapItem], launchOptions: launchOptions as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

to

```
MKMapItem.openMapsWithItems([currentLocationMapItem, mapItem], launchOptions: launchOptions)
```

That should work.

**Sidenote:** You should change your code style to allow Swift infer most types. Please stop hurting everyone's eyes with `var placemark:MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(...)`. Also try to avoid `NSDictionary`, please use Swift's `Dictionary`

Comment: @vrwim Reduntant typing ought to be a compiler warning. We should file radars.